# running rmi server, classnotfound

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi, rmiregistry

Hi I'm trying to run a java application that binds a class to the naming server, but i constantly get a ClassNotFoundException

First I start the registry:

> rmiregistry

then from eclipse I try to execute the server but get this error

> java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
>       java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: progInternet2008.commons.NominabileFactory
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:396)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
>       at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
>       at progInternet2008.Pozzobon.tesi.Slave.main(Slave.java:54)
>   Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: progInternet2008.commons.NominabileFactory
>       at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:386)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: progInternet2008.commons.NominabileFactory
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
>       at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyInterfaces(LoaderHandler.java:711)
>       at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:655)
>       at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:592)
>       at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:628)
>       at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:294)
>       at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:238)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1531)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1493)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
>       ... 12 more

I've read the RMI Java tutorial but still could not get it working...

As VM Arguments I've set this:

> -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:${workspace_loc}/progInternet2008

please help me

(I'm using Java 6)

Comment: Did you end up fixing this problem?

Comment: A file: codebase URL is only going to work when client and server are on the same machine, in which case you don't need the codebase feature at all, or when it refers to a shared drive that looks the same from client and server, which implies a LAN, where again it is dubious whether you need the feature at all.

Answer (score 74):

Run the `rmiregisrty` command from your /bin, /build, or /build/classes folder, whichever folder is the root of your built files.

I spent half a day trying to solve that same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much! It just worked for the easiest run (local only).

Comment: You saved 25 people!

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I needed! I took it a step further and just fired up the registry within my code using the command `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);`

Comment: How did you find that out?

Comment: @lolynns You deserve a medal

Comment: For intellij guys, the folder is out/production/myrmi. The one that has .class files

Answer (score 27):

The exception is occurring because the rmiregistry application doesn't know where to load classes from. When you attempt to bind an object in the RMI registry, the registry downloads the class definition for that object. Some of the other answers are telling you to get around this by setting the classpath for the rmiregistry app so that it has the class definitions when it is started and doesn't need to download anything, but Sun's Java RMI tutorial **[explicitly says not to do this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/rmi/running.html)**. I suspect this has the potential to cause conflicts between the version of the class in the registry and the class on the server.

The correct way to handle the problem is to set the java.rmi.server.codebase property as you were trying to do. The property requires that a directory path be terminated with a forward slash, like so:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:${workspace_loc}/progInternet2008/
```

You may also be having trouble if the ${workspace_loc} variable is a relative path and the rmiregistry application was not started in the same directory so the relative path is not correct for it. If you either make the path absolute, or start the rmiregistry in the appropriate directory, the ClassNotFoundException should go away. See the [tutorial on the java.rmi.server.codebase property](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html) for a little more detailed information.

Comment: The tutorial is only saying that because it is using the codebase feature, and it breaks the codebase feature. It's not a issue otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Okay I just overcame this problem.  Make sure when you run `rmiregistry` that your `CLASSPATH` environment variable is set.

For example, you might have a script:

```
set CLASSPATH=[path to jdbc driver].jar
rmiregistry.exe
```

This was all I needed to get my lost classpath working.  I'm not sure how to send `-cp commandline` to `rmiregistry.exe`.  Its documentation is quite lacking.

Comment: Sun's RMI tutorials explicitly tell you not to do this. It can cause problems.

Comment: @A.Levy Where exactly do they say that? The only way this can cause a problem is if the codebase feature is being used.

Comment: upvote. this is the only fix that works from the last 10 questions around. useCodeBaseOnly=false doesnt work as argument. -Djava.security.policy=file which sets all permissions doesnt work either. -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=some.jar doesn't work as noted by others...

Answer (score 5):

I'm fairly certain that you'll have to start your RMI server using the same classpath as your application. I believe it takes the same parameters as java, i.e. -cp `[your class path]`.

Comment: When you say RMI server do you mean the rmiregistry application or the server component of the application vs the client component?

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded from JDK1.6.0_33 to 1.7.0_45 and had the same problem. I found this document and resolved the problem by starting rmiregistry with:

rmiregistry -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false

Refer below
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/enhancements-7.html

Comment: Although this is the command provided in the linked article, it doesn't work as written. The property must be specified via -J-D, not just -D.

Answer (score 3):

Close the cmd window where the rmiregistry was initially started.In a fresh cmd go to the location where your project classfiles are located(uptill bin) and start the registry using the below command:

> rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false

If you are using Eclipse ,Run the ServerSideProject and your ImplementationClass Instance gets bound to the URL specified.

Just print a line below the the binding method and see to it whether it is gets printed. If it gets printed successfully it means your server is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

try to add /bin at the end of your VM Arg:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:${workspace_loc}/progInternet2008/bin
```

The file you will run are in this directory, so you need to include it in the path.

Comment: There is no evidence In the question about the class files being in the bin directory.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, to fix this ensure that your *CLASSPATH* is set to the path containing the server classes when running **rmiregistry**.

On a linux machine run the following commands.

```
export CLASSPATH="<server_class_path>"
```

Ensure the **CLASSPATH** has been set:

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

Once the class path has been set, run **rmiregistry**

```
rmiregistry &
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent a whole day uninstalling and reinstalling my JDK and changing the classpaths's and environment variables. But the culprit was that the command **start rmigregistry** didnt' start rmiregistry in a proper way. So, thanks for the comments on this page the solution was to *unset* the CLASSPATH temporarily. And that is done through the command `set CLASSPATH=`

Comment: Doesn't start it 'in the proper way' for *you,* using *your* CLASSPATH, which it can't know in advance. Getting that right is up to you. Don't blame the tools.