# RMI app throwing error while running from terminal but working ok with eclipse

Tags: java, client-server, rmi, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to develop a chat app, using java RMI, where multiple clients can interact with each other. The issue is, the codes are working well, atleast so far, in eclipse but when I try it from terminal using the standard procedures following rmic, start rmiregistry and initiate server and then client, its throwing a long list of ChatServer_stub.class ClassNotFoundException. ChatServer_stub.class is there, I mean I cant initiate a server without creating stub using rmic. anyideas??? I dont think this issue is anywhere related with the codes since it working with eclipse, so I am pasting just the errors here.
just in case..here are the codes : https://github.com/kumarsaurabh20/Programming_Test/tree/master/network_prog_Java/RMIChatApp/src

```
 Registry is created..
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ChatServer_Stub
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:419)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
at ChatServer.rebindChatServer(ChatServer.java:47)
at ChatServer.main(ChatServer.java:98)
    Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ChatServer_Stub
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:409)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ChatServer_Stub
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:451)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:182)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:220)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1609)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1768)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answe lies here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html

Found a similar question in this post with a well explained solution:
[running rmi server, classnotfound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464687/running-rmi-server-classnotfound?rq=1)

thanx A. Levy

Answer (score 1):

The Registry doesn't have the stub on its CLASSPATH. Either start the Registry such that it does, or use the codebase feature.