# My simple RMI server does not run

Tags: java, rmi

I'm new to RMI, and was following the Oracle's RMI tutorial code at **[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html)** and wrote something similar.

My code was working correctly, everything fine. But I didn't touch the code, and today after 3 weeks when I just came and tried to run it again , surprisingly **it was not running anymore**, and throws the following exception: (of course I did `start rmiregistry`).

**How can I fix the problem?** I am running Java 1.8.0.60 and use eclipse.

SOLUTION: I should have run `rmiregistry` in the `bin` folder (or probably set classpath with other ways).

```
Server exception: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Hello
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Hello
... continued ...
```

Here is the code for `HelloServer`:

```
package test;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class HelloServer implements Hello {

    public HelloServer() {}

    public String pollServer() {
        String data= EchoServerRMI.queuePoll();
        System.out.println("polling test"+data);
        return data;
//      return "1";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            HelloServer obj = new HelloServer();
            Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.bind("Hello", stub);
            System.err.println("Server ready");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for `Hello` class:

```
package test;

import java.rmi.*;

public interface Hello extends Remote {
    String pollServer() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Comment: can you replace your code with this public HelloServer()throws RemoteException  {}

Comment: It fixed it! How come it was running the other time? It was the same code I believe!

Comment: @vishalgajera There's no reason why that would fix the problem. Unless the remote object class extends `UnicastRemoteObject` or `Activatable` its constructor doesn't need to throw `RemoteException.` OP must have improved his deployment, or else he wasn't running the code he thought he was running.

Comment: Again, I run into the same problem. Same exception again...

Comment: Have you looked at the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464687/running-rmi-server-classnotfound)? Have you figured out what you changed between 'it fixed it!' and 'I run into the same problem'?

Comment: Yes, thanks. That was almost related. I should have run registry in the `bin` folder.